Proof or counterexample of the inclusion $\mathrm{Ass}(I)\subset\mathrm{Ass}(I^N)$ for monomial ideals
Let $I$ be a monomial ideal in the ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ with $k$ a field (let's say the real numbers). Let $\operatorname {Ass}(I)$ be the set of associated primes of $I$. In general, it is not true that $\operatorname {Ass}(I^N) \subset \operatorname {Ass}(I)$ for all natural numbers $N$, but what about the other inclusion? Consider for instance $R=k[x,y,z]$ and $I=\langle xy,xz,yz \rangle$. We find that a minimal primary decomposition for $I$ is given by $I=\langle x,y \rangle \cap \langle x,z \rangle \cap \langle z,y \rangle$ and thus $\operatorname {Ass}(I)=\{ \langle x,y \rangle, \langle x,z \rangle, \langle z,y \rangle \}$. On the other hand:
$$
I^2=\langle x^{2}z^{2},\,x^{2}y\,z,\,x\,y\,z^{2},\,x^{2}y^{2},\,x\,y^{2}z,\,y^{2}z^{2} \rangle,
$$
and  we also find $I^2= \langle y^2,x^2,xy \rangle \cap \langle z^2,x^2,xz \rangle \cap \langle y^2,z^2,yz \rangle \cap \langle y^2,x^2,z^2 \rangle$. Therefore, $\langle x,y,z \rangle \in 
\operatorname {Ass}(I^2)\setminus \operatorname {Ass}(I)$ and thus $\operatorname {Ass}(I^2) \not\subset \operatorname {Ass}(I)$. Nevertheless, in this case, it is true that $\operatorname {Ass}(I) \subset \operatorname {Ass}(I^2)$.

Is the inclusion $\mathrm{Ass}(I) \subset \mathrm{Ass}(I^N)$ always true for an arbitrary monomial ideal $I$?

I have been trying to prove it or give a counterexample without success.
Any help?
In advance thank you.

Here is a counterexample taken from [1, Example 4.18]:
Take $R=k[a,b,c,d,e]$ and $I=(ab^2c,bc^2d,cd^2e,de^2a,ea^2b)$. One can compute (using Macaulay2 for instance) that $(a,b,c,d,e)$ is an associated prime of $I$ but not of $I^2$.
References. 1. S. Morey and R. H. Villarreal, Edge ideals: algebraic and combinatorial properties, link.
